# Translating a SQL query to CAML query

Tags: sharepoint

I am new to CAML query and as much as I have expected it to be simple like SQL I have found it quite frustrating to deal with. I have a simple query SQL query I am trying to translate into CAML but do not receive the expected result.

Sql: `select * from exchangeRates where (date='2016-12-01' and  currency<>'DKK')`

Or

`(date='2016-11-25' and currency_Type = 'Manual')`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

#### Equals and Not Equals

Use the `<Eq>` element to find items where a field equals a specified value and the `<Neq>` element to find items where a field is not equal to a specified value.

```
<Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="Internal_Name_Of_Date_Field" />
    <Value Type="DateTime">2016-12-01</Value>
</Eq>
```

#### Joining Conditions to build Complex Conditionals

CAML uses `<And>` and `<Or>` elements to join conditions together within a `<Where>` clause.

```
<And>
    <Eq>
        ...
    </Eq>
    <Neq>
        ...
    </Neq>
</And>
```

Each `<And>` or `<Or>` element expects **exactly** two child nodes, which are the conditions being joined together.

A child node can be another `<And>` or `<Or>` element, allowing you to join nested conditions together for arbitrarily complex conditions.

```
<Or>
    <And>
       ...
    </And>
    <And>
        ...
    </And>
<Or>
```

#### Using Excel Formulas as Conceptual Guidelines

Sometimes it helps to think in terms of an Excel formula. The Excel functions `OR()` and `AND()` can take two parameters (conditions) to return a boolean value. CAML syntax and Excel syntax are thus pretty similar: CAML just uses XML elements instead of parentheses.

English: `(A and B) or (C and D)`

Excel: `OR( AND(A, B), AND(C, D) )`

CAML: `<Or> <And> A B </And> <And> C D </And> </Or>`

#### Example CAML

Without knowing what the internal names of your columns are, the `<Where>` element of your CAML query might look something like this:

```xml
<Where>
    <Or>
        <And>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="Internal_Name_Of_Date_Field" />
                <Value Type="DateTime">2016-12-01</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Neq>
                <FieldRef Name="Internal_Name_Of_Currency_Field" />
                <Value Type="Text">DKK</Value>
            </Neq>
        </And>
        <And>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="Internal_Name_Of_Date_Field" />
                <Value Type="DateTime">2016-11-25</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="Internal_Name_Of_Currency_Type_Field" />
                <Value Type="Text">Manual</Value>
            </Eq>
        </And>
    <Or>
</Where>
```